# How to resolve multiple scroll-bars issue coming in a single window?

Tags: javascript

> As i am having an scroll- bar on a pop-up menu but when i am expanding folders in it than it is showing multiple scroll bars, how can i show single scroll bar vertically and horizontally , whether i am expanding multiple folders to select a particular folder.
>   As i am using overflow:scroll property

```
 <div id="fileTree" class="layout-app" style="height: 360px; width: 550px;overflow: scroll;top:116px;"></div>
```

[image]

you can refer following fiddle for the expanding and collapse feature.
And the question is that how can i add single scroll-bar on that pop-up which is having this folder selection process.

http://jsfiddle.net/0L7hacjv/4/

Comment: Can't help much by just looking at the code, more info/code would be helpful

Comment: Please post your sample code. Or you can use this plugin [Jquery File Tree](https://www.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-file-tree)

Comment: Can't find your issue in the fiddle. Can you be more precise?

Comment: I don't understand what the issue is.  Does this solve your issue by adding style  `overflow: hidden;` to `tree-border` div. ?

Answer (score 0):

You either apply `overflow: hidden;` to the inner elements so they won't feature a scroll bar, but keep it for the parent element or customize the scroll bars so they aren't that prominent.

Answer (score 0):

`overflow: scroll` will always show a scrollbar even if it is not needed.
`overflow: hidden` will never show a scrollbar and would hide the content. 
`overflow: auto` will adjust itself and would show/hide the scrollbar as per available height.

You just need to re-structure your html so that the parent has `overflow: auto` and apply no overflow property to child elements.

This suggestion may or may not be correct as it is not very clear what code you are writing but hope i may have cleared a bit of confusion.